# Values for os.family in Maven profile activation condition

Tags: maven, environment-variables, maven-profiles

Maven allows to activate certain build profiles based on the operating system family it runs on, for example:

```xml
<profile>
    <activation>
        <os><family>Windows</family></os>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

There is a number of question around this: what are allowed values for `os.family` then? Are they case sensitive? Does Linux come across as `Unix`? Or `unix`? And so on.

Where can I find information about allowed values – or, at least, where does Maven take these values from? Environment variables?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The values are defined in the `plexus-utils` project, in [`Os.java`](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-utils/blob/f2beca21c75084986b49b3ab7b5f0f988021dcea/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/util/Os.java#L72). You can see [in `isOs`](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-utils/blob/f2beca21c75084986b49b3ab7b5f0f988021dcea/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/util/Os.java#L303) that the match is case-insensitive, that the value is taken from `System.getProperty( "os.name" )` and that you should specify `unix` to match a Linux platform.

Answer (score 37):

A very useful Maven command for checking these OS properties on your machine:

```
mvn enforcer:display-info
```

Example output on a SunOS / Sparc host:

```
[INFO] Maven Version: 3.0.4
[INFO] JDK Version: 1.6.0_34 normalized as: 1.6.0-34
[INFO] OS Info: Arch: sparc Family: unix Name: sunos Version: 5.8
```

Example output on a Linux host:

```
[INFO] Maven Version: 3.0.4
[INFO] JDK Version: 1.7.0_85 normalized as: 1.7.0-85
[INFO] OS Info: Arch: amd64 Family: unix Name: linux Version: 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: This is also the [suggested way](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) by Apache, which links to [this enforcer plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireOS.html) currently.

Answer (score 28):

OS family values:

```
dos
mac
netware
os/2
tandem
unix
windows
win9x
z/os
os/400
openvms
```

Other value you can get by run simple program:

```
public class SystemProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Os name: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
        System.out.println("Os arch: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
        System.out.println("Os version: " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This system information is needed for the Spring Boot environment profile activation using OS information.

Answer (score 9):

it might worth asking from maven help:

```
mvn help:system | grep "os\."
```

Comment: This is what I needed to identify the variable `${os.detected.name}` that I needed.